# QGIS triangular legend (RGB colour space)

Tags: gis, legend, rgb, pca, qgis

using QGIS, I have constructed a colour map that looks similar to the one below.
[image: Exemplary visualization].

I would like to obtain a similar triangular legend, but with the colours used in my RGB composite and based on the blending mode I used. I know how to construct bar colour ramps, but I struggle fitting the colour space present in my RGB composite to the desired layout, where each corner stands for a given colour channel. I have extensively searched the internet, but so far have found little. Can such task even be accomplished in QGIS? If it is possible, I appreciate every help!

Comment: To be more specific, I seem to need a triangular colour ramp with 3 reference points.

Comment: It seems one use additive (which has yellow) and one subtractive colour mixing. If you add luminosity to triangle, you should get the correct colours.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the issue is that I do not know how to add a third reference point.